# Identify number in a column that is not in sequential order

Tags: php

Using the data below, how do i print out that ID 5 is not in sequential descending order when it should be. How do I actually read the column, Value in the order that I want?

```
Id Value
1  5000
2  82 900
3  81 000
4  80 000
5  79 000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**Descending**  `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC`

**Ascending**  `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name ASC`

Answer (score 0):

In Sql,

SELECT column_name, column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;

This query can descend or ascend the column and get value

Comment: Okay, but how do I actually print out that ID 1 with the value 5000 is not in descending order?:)